# Pool mining using monerod.exe

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I was new in crypto mining and have one question. Is it possible to run pools mining using monero wallet gui?if it does how can i use it?

Comment: Are you asking if you can administer a pool?  Or are you asking if you can use the GUI to mine in a pool?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes i want to use the gui to mine in pools. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

No, its not possible with Monero GUI. In order to mine into pools, you need to use a stand-alone miner, such as [XMR CPU Stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu), and to launch it with the parameters provided by the mining pool.

## Long Answer

The Monero GUI comes in 2 parts, each running its own process:
 * THE GUI per se
 * The Monero daemon

When you mine with you GUI, it uses the miner which is in the daemon. This miner is designed to mine directly to the network. There is no option to mine into a pool.